# Application insights returns 400 error

Tags: angularjs, azure-application-insights

Today I found an issue with application insights. Now it returns me 400 error when I try to track event:

POST https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track
400 (106: Field 'type' on type 'Device' is of incorrect type. Expected: string, Actual: undefined)

Nothing was changed that can lead to this issues.
If I event try to provide it with type field it just cause an other error (type for User).

I'm using app insights via angularJs [module](https://github.com/khaines/angular-applicationinsights).

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I have just started getting this error also, it is occurring across all browsers. It looks to me like MS have deployed a new version of the script which is broken. Either that or they rolled out breaking changes with letting anyone know! Either are just as bad as each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got fixed in the latest version of the plugin (0.2.8). An update of the nuget package fixed this problem.

https://github.com/khaines/angular-applicationinsights/issues/35

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [SDK that you're using](https://github.com/khaines/angular-applicationinsights), it is community supported, so we are not doing validation on this SDK before making changes to our data collection endpoint.
You can see there's already [an issue opened](https://github.com/khaines/angular-applicationinsights/issues/35) against this SDK to address the problem that you are describing.

We recommend using [officially supported JS SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS) to ensure compatibility with data collection endpoint. We are continuously making improvements and [recently added auto-collection of AJAX request](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ajax-collection-in-application-insights/)s.